# Liquibase SQL Changeset Cannot Load CSV File : FileNotFoundException

Tags: war, liquibase, liquibase-sql

Using a SQL style approach to Liquibase changesets (which is our codestyle, we don't use XML) I am trying to load an CSV file using the following SQL changeset

**SQL**

```
-- changeset user:insert-prices-data-temp-table

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'foo/src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/2021/prices.csv'
INTO TABLE prices_temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

When deploying the WAR file to Wildfly the following exception

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> foo/src/resources/liquibase/changelogs/2021/prices.csv (No such file
> or directory) 2021-09-22T20:52:18.581085123Z  at
> java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
> 2021-09-22T20:52:18.581087214Z    at
> java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
> 2021-09-22T20:52:18.581089768Z    at
> java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
> 2021-09-22T20:52:18.581092029Z    at
> java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
> 2021-09-22T20:52:18.581094150Z    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendFileToServer(MysqlIO.java:3772)

The Master Change log file references the 2021 directory with the SQL and CSV file existing in the same directory.

```
<includeAll path="liquibase/changelogs/2021/" filter="xml" errorIfMissingOrEmpty="true" />
```

I have tried the following other paths but they all still yield a FileNotFoundException

- prices.csv
- liquibase/changelogs/2021/prices.csv
- WEB-INF/classes/liquibase/changelogs/2021/CCC-220-marking-time-prices.csv
- (Absolute path) /home/xxxx/Work/foo-service/foo/src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/2021/prices.csv

**Liquibase Version**: 3.5.1

**Wildfly Jboss Version** : 21

I have checked the CSV file is present in the WAR file

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use some mysql function `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` which doesn't know about your classpath. It's trying to look at your filesystem and such path doesn't exists. Even if you provide something like `yourapp.jar!liquibase/changelogs/2021/prices.csv` it won't be able to read that file. You will need to pull `prices.csv` out of your application to filesystem and point mysql function to that location.
Or you can use liquibase's [loadData](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/load-data.html) if that helps.